# Get "uid" of selected user Swift 3 Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

In my iOS app, I want to get the info of the user that I clicked on to display it on their profile.

I think this variable is different from the `currentUser` variable. How do I get that user's `uid`? What variables/references/child do I need to set?

Comment: The Firebase Authentication API only provides a way to get information about the currently signed in user. There is no public API to get the information of any other user. Most developers work around this by storing user information in the Firebase Database. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023038/how-to-create-a-friends-list-using-firebase).

Comment: How are you clicking on the user? i.e. what process code-wise are you doing to allow the user to click on another user?

Comment: The current user clicks on an UITapGestureRecognizer which covers a user's profile photo (UIImageView). The imageView is set in a tableView along with the user's main image post and username. The tableView is displaying a list of user's posts, like instagram or Facebook.

Comment: So you load the users into an array and that array is a dataSource for the tableView and/or is where you get the other users profile photo's from. If that's the case, then you must have something like a /users node in Firebase where you store the users uid. So when you load in your users, at that time also load in their uid's so when you click on it, you can retrieve the uid from the array of users. Also, see [Search User Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737009/how-do-you-search-access-users-data/33738253#33738253) and my answer.